# Is it possible to display Estimation Points for lanes in Active Sprint in JIRA?

Tags: estimation, jira, process, tools

in the attachment you can see JIRA, an active Scrum Board.
I've a very simple question, is it possible to have on top of the lane a number representing the Estimated Points that are the sum of that specific lane?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I'm certainly not aware of any out-of-the-box way to do it. There may be some ninja way (JIRA is pretty flexible if you dig into the guts of it). Apprehensive to list this as an answer since it could change any time Atlassian wants to tweak it. I can say that the numbers at the top are intended for use as a WIP limit, which would not use points, so I don't know how likely it is they'll ever put that in.

Comment: yeah, pity, i simply believe it's a real good place to display points.

Comment: What would be the usefulness?  A story point estimates the total complexity required to deliver the user story in its entirety from To Do, through Build to Test and into Done.   Any one column only represents a fraction of the points estimate.

Comment: True when you estimate STORIES (as Scrum is supposed to be) but in my team we adopted TASKS estimation (correct? wrong? for us it works very good) so it would be interesting to track those numbers / fractions. That's it.

Comment: The short answer is: no
The long answer is: no, it is not possible

As mentioned in the comments, it seems useless since the storypoints account for the story from to do to done and the columns only represent a small part of the work.

What I'm curious about is what you want to achieve by showing the number of storypoints in a lane? I have the feeling that you want to set a limit of sorts. If that is the case you could try to implement swarming so that team members focus on 1 issue and do everything they can to complete it before picking up a new one.